# Robust file system for embedded use

Tags: filesystems, embedded

I'm looking for realization of embbeded file system to store pieces of data in nand flash memory addressable by name. Target processor is ColdFire v2 running uC/OS-II, that's why huge FlashFX from datalight.com doesn't fit.
Such realization must be robust to occasional power off and erroneous of nand storage.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't looked at uC/FS with journaling enabled, then I would start there.

http://micrium.com/page/products/rtos/fs

journaling file systems are supposed to maintain the integrity of the FS during system failures.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system

Comment: I don't know of something cheaper, however you can probably get some free open source FS to work, but that will probably require a lot more work to integrate it into uC/OS, so the actual cost of development may not much cheaper than just using the journaling module which will should be quite easy to integrate.

Comment: Do you know tiny open source FS with journaling?
I don't need FS-calls to be reenterable, so OS-integration isn't a problem.

Comment: I really dont know of an FS that is: tiny, open source, and supports journaling. But you can look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems The features table on this page shows which FS supports journaling, unfortunately there aren't any tables that show the license or code size estimates.

Comment: Segger's [emFile](http://www.segger.com/emfile.html) has a journalling option, but given the close relationship between Micrium and Segger it may be identical to uC/FS and no less expensive.  There's a reason this stuff is not free - it is the hard work of fellow developers.

Comment: Thank you for link on emFile, It's interesting but I think I'll try to shrink ram usage of yaffs to fit available RAM.